# What are my alternatives to "instanceof" when the reference is null in Java?

Tags: java

I have a method that receives a parameter which can be null. I have used `instanceof` to check the type but if the parameter comes null, `instanceof` returns null. I have read the documentation and it is how `instanceof` works. In this case , I want to check the type of the passed parameter  even if the value is null.
example

```java
public static void checkType(Object yourObject) {
    if(yourObject instanceof String) {  // this fails if null passed, even if declared as String
    print("You have passed a String");    
    }
}
```

What could I do in these cases?

My goal is, that:

```java
String myvar = null; 
checkType(myvar);
```

would print:

> "You have passed a String"

Comment: I don't think you can check the type of a null reference, even at runtime.

Comment: `null` doesn't have a type.  `String a = null;` is the same as `Integer b = null;`, they're both null.  In Java (and most OOP) you have to separate the type of the variable from the type of the object the variable holds.  For example, you could say `Object obj = "abc";`.  Does that mean `"abc"` is not a string, just because you didn't declare it as a string?  No.  `"abc"` is still a string, you're just referencing it as an object.  Same goes here.  `null` is still `null`, no matter what you reference it as.

Comment: not a duplicate, but you may or may find it useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104708/typeof-in-java-8

Answer (score 5):

Let's say your goal is to have this code, with the output as indicated in the comments:

```java
String s = null;
Integer i = null;
checkType(s); // prints "String"
checkType(i); // prints "Integer"
```

Then this is impossible unless the two invocations of `checkType` are actually invoking different methods with the same name, i.e. overloads:

```java
static void checkType(String s) {
    System.out.println("String");
}
static void checkType(Integer i) {
    System.out.println("Integer");
}
```

This doesn't seem very useful, though, because the method is not actually checking the type; it's the compiler that's checking the type and calling the appropriate overload. You can't get the same result with a single method doing a runtime type check, because the value `null` doesn't carry the information you want at runtime; there aren't different "flavours" of `null`, all `null` values are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your parameter in a generic type

```
public class GenericClass<T> {

  private final Class<T> type;

  public GenericClass(Class<T> type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public Class<T> getMyType() {
    return this.type;
  }
}
```

from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime).

Comment: This is not an answer to the problem the OP is having.  The answer is simply "you can't do that".

Comment: @CryptoFool, the OP has asked for alternatives to what they have tried in the post. It seems they are well aware that "you can't do that". So if a null reference contains no runtime type information, the only alternative I can think of (with my limited imagination) is to include type information with the reference.